# How to prove this series identity involving Eisenstein series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series, modular-forms

I am stuck at proving the following identity
$$
    \sum_{k = 1}^{+\infty} \frac{ \prod_{i = 1}^4(b_i^k - b_i^{-k}) }{ (q^{k/2} - q^{-k /2})^2 }
    = \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }\sum_{\alpha_i = \pm 1}(\prod_{i = 1}^4 \alpha_i) E_2\Big[
\begin{matrix}
    1 \\ \prod_{i = 1}^4 b_i^{\alpha_i}
\end{matrix}
\Big] \ ,
$$
where we define the twisted Eisenstein series for $\phi = e^{2\pi i \lambda}$ with $\lambda \in [0,1)$, $\theta \ne 1$,
\begin{align}
 E_{k \ge 1}\left[\begin{matrix}
  \phi \\ \theta
 \end{matrix}\right] \equiv & \ - \frac{B_k(\lambda)}{k!} \\
 & \ + \frac{1}{(k-1)!}\sum_{r \ge 0} \frac{(r + \lambda)^{k - 1}\theta^{-1} q^{r + \lambda}}{1 - \theta^{-1}q^{r + \lambda}}
 + \frac{(-1)^k}{(k-1)!}\sum_{r \ge 1} \frac{(r - \lambda)^{k - 1}\theta q^{r - \lambda}}{1 - \theta q^{r - \lambda}} \ .
\end{align}

I was able to prove a similar equality,
$$
    \sum_{k = 1}^{+\infty} \frac{ \prod_{i = 1}^3(b_i^k - b_i^{-k}) }{ (q^{k/2} - q^{-k /2}) }
    = \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }\sum_{\alpha_i = \pm 1}(\prod_{i = 1}^3 \alpha_i) E_1\Big[
\begin{matrix}
    -1 \\ \prod_{i = 1}^3 b_i^{\alpha_i}
\end{matrix}
\Big] \ ,
$$
by using
\begin{align}
 \sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^n}{q^{- \frac{n}{2}} - q^{\frac{n}{2}}} = \sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{x q^{n + \frac{1}{2}}}{1 - x q^{n + \frac{1}{2}}} \ ,
\end{align}
and noticing that
\begin{align}
 E_1\left[\begin{matrix}
  -1 \\ x
 \end{matrix}\right] = - B_1(1/2)
 + \sum_{r = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{x^{-1} q^{r + \frac{1}{2}}}{1 - x^{-1}q^{r + \frac{1}{2}}}
 - \sum_{r = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{x q^{r + \frac{1}{2}}}{1 - x q^{r + \frac{1}{2}}} \ ,
\end{align}

However, I have failed so far trying to apply a similar trick.

Comment: where is this identity from? reference and some background motivation please.

Comment: @jimjim It appears in my ongoing study on superconformal index by equating different ways of writing the same quantity. The identity shown above is the simplest entry of an infinite family. Unfortunately I don't know of other references; I guess it could be some known identity in the math community.